how to fix this "Deployed contract to: undefined" How do i get the the contract address it got deployed to?
scripts.js
// imports
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
//async main
async function main() {
    const SimpleStorageFactory =
        await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage");
    console.log("Deploying contract...");
    const simpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploy();
    await simpleStorage.waitForDeployment(1);
    // what is the private key?
    // what is the rpc url
    console.log(`Deployed contract to: ${simpleStorage.address}`);
}

//main
main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });



hardhat.config.js
require("dotenv").config();

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */

const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
    networks: {
        sepolia: {
            url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 11155111,
        },
    },
    solidity: "0.8.24",
};

output
yarn run v1.22.22
warning ../../package.json: No license field
$ /home/phavezizzy/hh-fcc/hardhat-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/.bin/hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia
Deploying contract...
Deployed contract to: undefined
Done in 11.86s.```


In the scripts.js, just change the "address" to "target"
 console.log(`Deployed contract to: ${simpleStorage.target}`);

Or, you can also use await simpleStorage.getAddress().
